# How to make an image appear when I hover over a button (No inheritance)

Tags: css

```
<div class="a">
 <img class="img_c" id="img_id" src="~~">
 <div class="b">
  <div class="c">
   <ul class="d" id="e">
    <li ~~~ >
   </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

I want to display the image by hovering the cursor over the e button.
The b class has a max-width attribute, but the image is not bounded by the width, so it must be outside the class b.
How do I write CSS code in this case?

Comment: Please share some CSS part & where is button ?

Comment: The button is 'e'.

Comment: #img_id {
 position : absolute;
 top : 73.5px;
 height : 65px;
 z-index : -800;
 display : none;
}

Comment: Then where is `button` tag, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Sorry. There is no button tag. I wanted to make the image appear when I hovered over the area with the id "e", but I did not know the code.  /////        .e:hover #img_id { display : block; } doesn't work.

Comment: I don't think you can style the parent by hovering over a child using pure css. Can you use javascript?

Comment: Okay can you make a working fiddle with css

Comment: I can use javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use jQuery you can use something like this to show/hide the image.

```js
$("#e li").hover(
  function () {
    $("#img_id").show();
  }, 
  function () {
    $("#img_id").hide();
  }
);
```

```css
#img_id {
   display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="a">
 <img class="img_c" id="img_id" src="~~">
 <div class="b">
  <div class="c">
   <ul class="d" id="e">
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
    <li>item 3</li>
    <li>item 4</li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```